# RGBDSLAM tutorial with fuerte

Tags: slam, navigation, rgbd-slam, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When going through the rgb-d slam tutorial, rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam does not work on Fuerte. What would the new command be, and does anything else need to be changed for the newer ROS versions? Or is there a new tutorial? Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38666/rgbdslam-tutorial-with-fuerte/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-07-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on 2012-07-12**:
Are you encountering compilation problems? If so, check this question http://answers.ros.org/question/33515/rgbdslam-problem-compilation-fuerte-and-cv-240/

**Comment by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on 2012-07-12**:
Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately, I can't compile anything in the first place with the rosmake --rosdep-install command. I have the rgbdslam folder in my ros_workspace, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Should I build or launch or something else? Thank you.

**Comment by [derekjchow](https://answers.ros.org/users/2190/derekjchow/) on 2012-07-12**:
Could you post the error message you get when you run "rosmake --rosdep-install"? It's hard to determine the cause of your problem without any symptoms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Internal use of rosdep inside rosmake was removed in ROS Fuerte (see REP 125)

You'll now have to use

rosdep install PACKAGE

rosmake PACKAGE

---

Originally posted by [yglee](https://answers.ros.org/users/2776/yglee/) with karma: 60 on 2012-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RGBD Slam is not supported on Fuerte, I would advice you to install Ros Electric. however, It seems to be hard to install the full ros electric now because PCL and some others packages seems to not exist anymore in their original version.

I had some difficulties to make it work and I finally succeeded by installing this linux distribution which have already the full ros electric installed: http://openqbo.org/wiki/doku.php?id=download
After that, I followed the Rgbdslam tutorial and it finally worked.
Good luck to you !

---

Originally posted by [Absy](https://answers.ros.org/users/2645/absy/) with karma: 43 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1